# chrome tool tip bubble will appear ever time the application opens

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, chromium

Every time i start Chromium a tool tip appears pointing to the address bar saying.

> Search using Google right here type to search or enter a URL to navigate - everything just works

I've have been looking in the files it creates when i first ran chrome but no luck. is there a way to turn this off, disable tool tips?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried clicking on the tooltip?
2. Check the program folder (where the executable is); see if there is a (0-byte) file named `First Run` in there. If not, create one.